# Origine e significato dell'espressione “Pieno di super”

Tags: meaning, idioms

Rossana Campo ha scritto il libro *Il pieno di super*. 
Mi sapreste dire qual è  il senso di questa frase? Sarei inoltre curiosa di sapere da dove nasce questa espressione.

Grazie!

Comment: Benvenuta su Italian.SE! Cosa vuoi dire con "se è proprio questo il senso della frase"? A quale senso ti riferisci?

Comment: A me fa pensare alla benzina.

Comment: Se ne parla [qui](https://dizionaripiu.zanichelli.it/parola-del-giorno/2009/07/02/la_parola_del_giorno__non_plus_ultra__super/): *[fare il pieno](https://dizionario.internazionale.it/parola/fare-il-pieno) di super* significa riempire completamente il serbatoio di un veicolo di benzina super.

Comment: Forse stai semplicemente chiedendo qual è il significato dell'espressione e non hai saputo esprimerti bene?

Comment: Mi è stato detto che la frase "Il pieno di super" era "slang" tra i giovani italiani.

Dalle mie visite alle stazioni di servizio italiane, conosco il termine: "mi fa il pieno con il super, per piacere!"

Comment: Ho modificato il testo della domanda perché così com'era non si capiva molto. Ti sembra bene?

Comment: Va bene - sono un danese che vuole imparare la lingua italiana.

Comment: Quindi dovrebbe anche dire "sono curios**o**" e non "curios**a**"?

Answer (score 7):

In Italia *Super* è (tra le altre cose) il nome di un tipo di benzina. In questo caso la frase significa inequivocabilmente

> Il pieno di [benzina] Super

(qui *pieno* è utilizzato nel significato 8.c del [dizionario Treccani](http://www.treccani.it/vocabolario/pieno1/), cioè come *rifornimento completo*).

Comment: Il libro in questione risale al 1993, quando in Italia si usava il piombo tetraetile come antidetonante nella benzina. A quel tempo esistevano due tipi di benzina, normale e super, che si distinguevano in base al numero di ottano. I motori con alto rapporto di compressione richiedevano l'uso di benzina super, che era anche più costosa.

Comment: Mi è stato detto che la frase "Il pieno di super" era "slang" tra i giovani italiani.

Dalle mie visite alle stazioni di servizio italiane, conosco il termine: "mi fa il pieno con il super, per piacere!"

Comment: Non saprei. Nel '93 ero un po' troppo giovane per conoscere lo slang dei giovani... Purtroppo non ho accesso al libro per verificare.

Comment: Direi che non si trattava di "slang", era un termine usato abitualmente da chiunque, abbreviazione di "benzina super", che era il nome ufficiale. La super, al femminile, non "il" super. DI fatto quasi nessuno usava più la benzina normale nel '93, dato che aveva un numero di ottano intorno a 85, troppo poco per i motori più comuni. Pochi anni dopo si è passati alla benzina verde per tutti.

Comment: Questa spiegazione sembra giusta.

Grazie

Comment: @CasaMich: Può darsi che il titolo abbia un doppio senso: d'una parte, l'espressione che si dice al benzinaio; dall'altra, il linguaggio degli adolescenti che è "pieno di super".

Comment: @CasaMich: In questa [descrizione del libro di Google Books](https://books.google.es/books/about/Il_pieno_di_super.html?id=y0X924zqjNkC&redir_esc=y) si spiega: «Le comiche avventure di un gruppo di ragazzine molto curiose di scoprire qualunque cosa riguardi i baci, l'amore, il sesso, e che affrontano insieme prove terribili: la scuola con la maestra razzista, il catechismo repressivo di suor Pescecane, la scoperta dei maschi, di quelli scemi e di quelli troppo furbi...».

Comment: "Mi fa il pieno con il super, per piacere!": non è un “termine” insolito né uno slang speciale, è una normale frase italiana con cui si chiede al benzinaio quello che si desidera.

Comment: @DaG: So che non si tratta di "slang", ma penso che il titolo possa fare riferimento al fatto che gli adolescenti usino la parola "super" per parlare di molte cose diverse.

Comment: @DaG: Cercando la parola "super" all'interno del libro di Google Books, ho trovato questa frase: «Certe volte fermandosi per uno spuntino e un bicchiere a volte invece chiudendosi in camera da letto per **fare il pieno di super** alla sua innamorata Peperina.» Immagino che questo utilizzo di "fare il pieno di super" sia lo "slang" dei giovani italiani di cui parla l'OP.

Comment: @Charo: Mai sentito, ma non vuol dire niente. Per quel che conta, il ricco repertorio *Scrostati gaggio! Dizionario storico dei linguaggi giovanili* di Ambrogio e Casalegno non registra “super” e registra “pieno” solo come aggettivo, nel senso di “drogato”. Sospetto che la cosa migliore sia leggere il libro della Campo.

Comment: @DaG: E anche questo: «Mizzica! Ci aveva una sottana nera, transparente! Mi-inchiiiaaaa... quella è una bella fica, me la farei subito! fa Tore. E che avete fatto? **Avete fatto il pieno di super**? chiede la Dani. Abbiamo fatto un sessantanove e una pecorina, spiega Lupo. Minchia, commenta Tore con le orecchie viola. Cos'è un settantanove? chiede la Dani. Cos'è il pecorino? chiedo io.»

Comment: @DaG: E anche questo: «Che porci! Dice la Gabri. Cosa vuol dire gustare? Dice la Dani. La Silvia aggiunge: Certe volte invece dice: Vieni che **ti faccio il pieno di super**.» E sembra che in libro ci siano molte altre aparizioni di questa espressione che no riesco a visualizzare.